# fetching indexes of 1st occurance of elements in a series in a dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider a python dataframe

```
A      B         C  
1      random    imp1  
2      random    imp2  
5      random    imp3   
1      yes       ---  
2      yes       ---   
3      no        ---   
4      no        ---  
5      yes       ---
```

Whenever column B has a value yes, I want to fetch values of A. And eventually for those values of A, I want C when those values occurred 1st in A. So in this case, I finally want imp1, imp2 and imp3.

Is there an elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use this one-liner:

```
df[df.A.isin(df[df.B == 'yes'].A)].drop_duplicates('A').C
```

Output:

```
0    imp1
1    imp2
2    imp3
Name: C, dtype: object
```

Comment: @jezrael Why is it the dot notation for the columns adding extra translation?

Comment: @jezrael df[df.A.isin(df[df.B == 'yes'].drop_duplicates('A').A)].C Should be better?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc` first, then [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and last filter with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) by values `a`:

```
a = df.loc[df['B'] == 'yes', 'A']
df = df.drop_duplicates('A')
df = df.loc[df['A'].isin(a), 'C']
print (df)
0    imp1
1    imp2
2    imp3
Name: C, dtype: object
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000

df = pd.DataFrame({'B': np.random.choice(['yes','no', 'a', 'b', 'c'], N),
                   'A':np.random.randint(1000, size=N),
                   'C':np.random.randint(1000, size=N)})
print (df)

print (df[df.A.isin(df[df.B == 'yes'].A)].drop_duplicates('A').C)
print (df[df.A.isin(df[df.B == 'yes'].drop_duplicates('A').A)].C)

def fjez(df):
    a = df.loc[df['B'] == 'yes', 'A']
    df = df.drop_duplicates('A')
    return  df.loc[df['A'].isin(a), 'C']

def fpir(df):
    a = df.A.values
    b = df.B.values == 'yes'
    d = df.drop_duplicates('A')
    return d.C[np.in1d(d.A.values, a[b])]


print (fjez(df))
print (fpir(df))
```

---

```
In [296]: %timeit (df[df.A.isin(df[df.B == 'yes'].A)].drop_duplicates('A').C)
1 loop, best of 3: 226 ms per loop

In [297]: %timeit (df[df.A.isin(df[df.B == 'yes'].drop_duplicates('A').A)].C)
1 loop, best of 3: 185 ms per loop

In [298]: %timeit (fjez(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 156 ms per loop

In [299]: %timeit (fpir(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 87.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: works fine, drop duplicates won't be needed in my case :)

Comment: Super, glad can help! Do you think dont need `drop_duplicates('A')` in real data?

Comment: wait sorry, it will be needed. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: No problem ;) I try find some data where is it not necessary but I cant.

Answer (score 1):

This should be very fast

```
a = df.A.values
b = df.B.values == 'yes'
d = df.drop_duplicates('A')
d.C[np.in1d(d.A.values, a[b])]

0    imp1
1    imp2
2    imp3
Name: C, dtype: object
```

---

Over the top approach.  About 50% faster than my other approach.

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def proc(f, m):
    mx = f.max() + 1
    a = [False] * mx
    b = [0] * mx
    z = [0] * f.size

    for i in range(f.size):
        x = f[i]
        y = m[i]
        b[x] += 1
        z[i] = b[x]
        a[x] = a[x] or y

    return np.array(z) == 1, np.array(a)[f]

df.C[np.logical_and(*proc(pd.factorize(df.A.values)[0], df.B.values == 'yes'))]

0    imp1
1    imp2
2    imp3
Name: C, dtype: object
```